# Codeigniter php tags stripping with xss_clean

Tags: php, codeigniter, xss, htmlspecialchars

Why if i pass a `$_POST['string'] = "<?php echo 'hey' ?>"` then i pass it to the xss_clean() with echo `$this->input->post('string',true);` it is outputted as  `&amp;lt;?php echo 'hey' ?&amp;gt;` and not as  `&lt;?php echo 'hey' ?&gt;` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the source code, you can see that the xss_clean method does a lot of heavy lifting. It's more than just a `htmlspecialchars()` call.  If you're wanting to display php code in a page, I would convert it first, then sanitize it.